# jQuery Tablesorter first sort click descending

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

So I know you can set the default sort order of specific columns with tablesorter. This is a bit different.

If you click any non-sorted column, the first sort is always **^** (asc). I want the first click to be **V** (desc).

Any idea what this option would be in the API? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get jQuery Tablesorter to sort descending by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614390/how-to-get-jquery-tablesorter-to-sort-descending-by-default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a dup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
      $("#theTable").tablesorter({ 
        sortInitialOrder: 'desc',
        sortList: [[3,1]] // etc.

       }); 
    } 
    ); 
</script>
```

[How to get jQuery Tablesorter to sort descending by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614390/how-to-get-jquery-tablesorter-to-sort-descending-by-default)

Comment: I think he's asking the default behavior on the first **click** instead.

Comment: @inhan this seems to end up making the first click a desc click for the whole table (working).

Comment: It is strange that if I sort one column desc, then click another to sort it desc, when I go back to the original column to sort desc again, it ends up being asc. I wish that it was consistently the first action for a non-sorted column

Comment: @tester that's exactly what I meant - to change default behavior of the first click sort type.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across this same issue.  None of the answers here or elsewhere solved it to my satisfaction.  Digging into the tablesorter code reveals another option called sortRestart that seems to force any new clicks to a column to sort according to sortIntialOrder, even if those columns had been clicked previously:

```
table.tablesorter({
  sortInitialOrder: 'desc',
  sortRestart: true,
  sortList: [[2,1]]
});
```

The above worked for me.